# Trouble understanding storage allocation in Kip Irvine's assembly language book

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

I read the book [Assembly Language for x86 by Kip Irvine](http://kipirvine.com/asm/). On page 85 he wrote the following about why to use symbols:

> Using the `DUP` Operator: `Section 3.4.4` showed how to use the `DUP` operator to create storage for arrays and strings. The counter used by `DUP` should be a symbolic constant, to simplify program maintenance. In the next example, if COUNT has been deﬁned, it can be used in the following data deﬁnition:
>
> ```
> array dword COUNT DUP(0)
> ```

I don't understand what this command is doing. Can someone explain to me what it means?

Comment: An array of `COUNT` dwords set to `0`.

Comment: Are you using MASM(or TASM) as your assembler, and did you define _COUNT_ first? Assume _COUNT_ is defined then `array dword COUNT DUP(0)` would set aside memory for an array of  _COUNT_ _DWORD_ elements initialized to 0. The label for the start of this memory is `array`.

Comment: @Jester array is keyword?

Comment: No, that's the name.

Comment: @MokholiaPokholia Something close in _C_ (assuming signed 32-bit integers) would be `#define COUNT 10` `static int32_t array[COUNT] = {0};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple:

```
.const
  COUNT equ 10               ; sets COUNT to a value of 10 or whatever
.data
  array dword COUNT DUP(0)   ; creates an array of DWORDs/4-byte values
```

So `array` consists of COUNT(=10) `DWORD` values equal to '0' (4*10 = 40 bytes).

The `DUP` command just says that the preceding data type is 'duplicated' COUNT times. So an `array` of `DWORD`s `DUP`ed by `COUNT` results in an address called `array` followed by (sizeof(DWORD)*COUNT) bytes initialized as `DWORD`s with the value 0.

Comment: Is it possible make it more simple?

Comment: Well, that's difficult. `array` is just the label. And at this label 4*10=40 bytes are reserved (for whatever). These 40 bytes are considered as 10 DWORDs(4 byte each) which each have the initial value of 0.

Comment: @MokholiaPokholia: sure, hard-code the count and then it's just `array: dword 10 DUP(0)`.  You still have to make sure you put it in the section you want it in.  (`.data`, `.rodata`, or `.bss` if Windows has a BSS.)